# ¿Alguien sabe como solucionar este error al crear un proyecto laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, composer

[image: Error al crear proyecto laravel]

Al querer crear un proyecto nuevo en laravel, me genera un error y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: Te falta la extensión fileinfo de php que te está indicando ahí

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo solucioné

Comment: Genial. Sería útil que escribas una respuesta explicando como lo solucionaste. También si editas la pregunta poniendo el mensaje de error como texto en vez de una imagen para que pueda ser indexado por un buscador. Si lo haces, tu pregunta/respuesta podría ser útil para otros usuarios con el mismo problema.